# Excel VBA subscript out of range when accessing results from worksheet function "Mode_Mult "

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of value from `Cells(1,1)` to `Cells(10,1)`. See below, this range needs to return multi modes 3 and 4. I have created the little codes, but it give me error

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Any thoughts?

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
```

```
Sub ModeXY()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 1))

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim varMode_Mult As Variant
    Debug.Print R.Address
    varMode_Mult = WorksheetFunction.Mode_Mult(R)
    Debug.Print UBound(varMode_Mult)
    For i = 1 To 2
        Debug.Print varMode_Mult(i) 'this gives me the Subscript out of range   error.
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of Mode_Mult is actually a 2 dimensional array, so you need to use:

```
Debug.Print varMode_Mult(i, 1)
```

to access the elements.